# Identify all (arp) devices on network regardless of ip

Tags: resolution, arp

I have a miss-configured device on the network where I don't know its IP-address.

However since I do know all other devices I want to lookup its IP by using arp. Consider the IP might be on an different subnet, so OSI level 3 tools might not work in this case. Is there a way to broadcast on OSI level 2 to ask for a resolution of all devices and then using tcpdump to identify the answers?

I am wondering if there is such a tool?

Comment: This should not be possible, because routers in general do not forward broadcasts (unless configured otherwise). See https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/58997/do-routers-forward-broadcast-traffic

Comment: Do you mean that the device might be configured for a different IP network, but still physically on the same ethernet (same broadcast domain) as you?